# Need help to form Jquery to slide a table row down if mouse hovers over previous(one up) table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Only scrolls up on pageload so far and even then the animation is jittery
and ugly. I suspect it's something to do with me wanting to use this on tr element.

```
<table>

    <tr class="ItemHeading">
    <td>ItemName</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="ItemDescription">
    <td>
    <ul>
    <li>Item spec</li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">



    $(".ItemDescription").slideUp(300);

        $(".ItemHeading").hover(function () {
            $(this).next("tr").slideDown(300);
        });


        $(".ItemHeading").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).next("tr").slideUp(300);
        });

 //  $(document).ready(function() {  $(".ItemDescription").slideUp(300); } );
    </script>
```

The below works fine, but it doesn't slide the table row up and down, just hides and shows. Provided
I set the .ItemDescription css display property to none.

```
    $('.ItemHeading').hover(function () {
    $(this).next("tr").css("display", "block");
    $(this).mouseleave(function () { $(".ItemDescription").css("display", "none"); });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest against tables with animations. It's just not going to give you the results you're looking for.

Also, you're using `closest` incorrectly. `closest` will go up the DOM to find the "closest" parent that matches the provided selector. You're looking for `next` which will select the following row.

html:

```
<div class="table">

    <div class="tr ItemHeading">
        <div class="td">ItemName</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tr ItemDescription">
        <div class="td">
            <ul>
                <li>Item spec</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".ItemDescription").slideUp(300);

$(".ItemHeading").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).next(".tr").slideDown(300);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).next(".tr").slideUp(300);
    }
);
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/VKBYy/1/

Comment: Thanks, interesting though that both slideUp and slideDown are triggered by hover event and do not interfere with one another? I would have thought it have to be something like mouseleave to trigger the slideUp?

Comment: `hover` has 2 different syntaxes. `hover(handlerIn(e), handlerOut(e))` or just `hover(handlerInOut(e))`. See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: So more explicitly, the first function I pass is only executing on hover over, while the second function is only executing on hover out. When you only specify one function to `hover`, that function is run both times. So for example, you could just pass one function with a toggle, and it will switch on when hover, and off when you leave.